# Python - Importing file from subpackage

Tags: python, import

I have following directory structure:

- /

  - package/

    - subpackage/

      - __init__.py
      - file.py
    - __init__.py
    - file.py
  - main.py

**/package/subpackage/__init__.py** has following code:

```
from .. import file;
```

It imports **/package/file.py** as expected.

**/main.py** has following code:

```
from package import subpackage as foo;
from package.subpackage import file as bar;
```

Last line imports **/package/file.py**, not **/package/subpackage/file.py**. **bar.__name__** confirms it. Why? What's wrong?

Python 2.5.2. Each file has

```
from __future__ import absolute_import;
```

at beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, it does exactly what you told it to:

When you import `package.subpackage`, you're executing `/package/subpackage/__init__.py`. And there you do `from .. import file`. So `file` in `package.subpackage` is `package.file`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it imports `file` from `..`, just as your first snippet says.